# REST structure; get first/last element of collection?

Tags: rest

I'm working on a REST interface, but am not sure of the best way to structure a "get first/last element" on a collection?

Eg, different options might be:

```
GET cart/product?id=first_element

GET cart/products?filter=first_element

... something else?
```

If there is a "standard" way of doing this, what is it? If there is no standard way, how would you do it and why?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the second option:

```
GET /cart/products?filter=first_element
```

`id` should be reserved for identity.

You could also do something like this:

```
GET /cart/products/12    # a product identified by ID
GET /cart/products/first # a product identified by a pseudo ID
GET /cart/products/last  # a product identified by a pseudo ID
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but then we'd need to query two resources instead of one, and that seems bad to me - should I be worried about this or is it "normal"?

Comment: Well "GET /cart/products?filter=first_element" would return something like "/cart/products?id=<id>", and then we'd need to check that resource to get the info, whereas "/cart/product?id=first" would return the product info directly, no?

Comment: Yes - I am sure that will work as well, I'm just wondering what the best / most standard way of doing this is, and what the reasoning behind structuring it in a certain way is :)